# Update mySQL from update link

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following link on index page

```
<td align="center"><a href="../athena/admin/update.php?id=' . $data ["keyword"] . ' ">update</a></td>
```

and this is the page it goes to ... Update.php
and here is the code

```
$id=$_GET['keyword'];

<tr><td>  Keyword:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" value="<? echo $id['keyword']; ?>">
```

I want the keyword to be automatically inserted into the form so that the rest of info can be updated.  How can i accomplish this?  For some reason this is not working.  It is putting the keywork in the URL ?id=KEYWORD on the update page but not displaying in the form.  Prob something stupid im sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either use `$_GET['id']` or change the link href to `../athena/admin/update.php?keyword=`. Currently, you are not looking for the `id` parameter, which contains the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
<? echo $id['keyword']; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id); ?>
```

Note:

- I used normal php tags instead  of short tags, just in case;
- I used `htmlspecialchars` to avoid errors and javascript nastiness; always prepare your data for the medium you are outputting to.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your variable name again.

Here, you pass .php?id= as your GET parameter:

```
<td align="center"><a href="../athena/admin/update.php?id=' . $data ["keyword"] . ' ">update</a></td>
```

In the Update.php, I think you were just misnamed it, it was supposed to be:

```
$id = $_GET["id"]; //not $_GET["keyword"]
```

The code below will output all the GET parameter, usually useful to debug in a simple PHP app:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_GET);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Hope it helped.

Edit: there is no println in php. Use print_r() or var_dump()

Comment: +1 most complete answer and mentioning a simple debug method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=$_GET['keyword'];

<tr><td>  Keyword:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
```

May be like this?